# pass arguments to unix shell script thru java

Tags: java

how to pass arguments to unix shell script thru java? I tried below code but it did not work.can you please suggest on this.

```
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/prgm/bin/java/t1.sh");
  pb.environment().put("param1", "Hi");
  Process p = pb.start();     // Start the process.
```

Comment: `new ProcessBuilder("/home/prgm/bin/java/t1.sh", "hi", "gopal");`

Comment: it worked but i want to pass java variable to unix shell script.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do 
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/prgm/bin/java/t1.sh Hi");

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Using below code, we can pass java variable to unix shell script as parameter

String var1="Hi";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/gcharpe/bin/java/t1.sh",var1);